# Strangeness using /usr/xpg4/bin/tr and /usr/bin/tr on Solaris 9

Tags: string, unix, solaris, sunos

I have a file looking like this,

```
"xxxxxx"
"yyyyyy"
"aaaaaa"
"cccccc"
"bbbbbb"
"eeeeee"
"oooooo"
"zzzzzz"
```

Wanting to replace each `\n` in this file I use:

```
tr '\n' ',' < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Which works fine. The output is to be expected:

```
"xxxxxx","yyyyyy","aaaaaa","cccccc"....
```

**However**

I can't do any manipulation using `sed` or `awk` on this file, none what so ever (the result is always blank, like: `sed 's/,/hello/g'` displays nothing), in Linux using the GNU package this works fine, but with non GNU not. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is because you replaced the last newline with a comma. So non GNU `sed` and `awk` just stop on end of file and do not parse the line because it is not terminated by `\n`.

Comment: Yes, you're probably correct I just used `awk` to remove the newlines and the result is the same. Just going verify the result via avoid removing the last `\n`